Azure DevOps YAML CI/CD pipeline show changes as part of "view changes" which were already deployed as part of earlier run
While running Azure CI/CD YAML pipeline, it shows "view XXX changes" e.g. "view 10 changes" which are being deployed as part of the CI/CD run. The CI/CD pipeline is triggered on merge completion as part of pull request.
When we click on view changes to find out what changes are being deployed as part of the pipeline run, we observe that it lists the new commits and also some older commits as well which were already deployed as part of previous CI/CD pipeline runs and as part of a different pull request.
Are we missing some configuration? What changes can we implement to see only new changes in "view XXX changes" option.


Try merging or rebasing changes from master branch right before creating the pull request.

We are following 2 branch approach i.e. dev and main which are long living branches. During project setup dev branch was created from main branch. Now the flow is feature branch --to-> dev (using PR)  and dev --to-> main (using PR).
Are you suggesting to try merging or rebasing from main --to--> dev branch ?

Ok, let me rephrase it: try merging or rebasing changes from the target branch right before creating the pull request - for example, from dev when the flow is feature branch --to--> dev (using PR).

ok. let me try that.

You may double check if those commits are following the scenario below.

Current commit (C1) being built;
Commit (C2) of the last successful build of the same source branch.
The commits between C1 and C2 in the commit tree.

